Understanding udev's ID_PATH for USB devices
When plugging different peripherals into the same USB port, the udev ID_PATH reports slightly different values.
Peripheral A: platform-fe9c0000.xhci-usb-0:1:1.0
Peripheral B: platform-fe9c0000.xhci-usb-0:1:4.2

I'd like to understand the naming scheme and the difference in the trailing portion (1.0 vs 4.2). I've tried searching the udev documentation but didn't have any luck. Is this explained/documented somewhere?
In case helpful/relevant, have collected the above on an RPi 4 running Debian Bookworm.

Maybe it's a coded device vendor name?

After the last colon, the two numbers X.Y identify the USB device configuration X and interface Y, in that order.
If a device has more than one configuration, one of them is designated the default configuration: the one the device powers up in, unless the host explicitly tells the device to switch to a different configuration. lsusb -v will show the number of available configurations as numConfigs and the number of the default configuration in another field.
An example might be a device that initially pretends to be a CD-ROM drive containing a Windows/Mac driver for the device. The driver (or in Linux, often the usb-modeswitch utility invoked by a udev rule) then tells the device to switch to a different configuration, causing the emulated USB CD-ROM to vanish and the real device functionality to become available.
Another example might be a USB 4G modem, which might offer one configuration as three serial ports (one for emulated PPP data connection similar to analog telephone modems, one for out-of-band status access, and one for GPS location info), another configuration for more modern "network-adaper-like" communication protocol, and another vendor-specific mode for firmware updates and special configuration.
The interface numbers are device-specific; only the control interface #0 is guaranteed to exist in all USB devices. For other interfaces, if the device conforms to some standardized USB device type, the device type specification might tell what each interface will be used for, or it might (more commonly) specify a particular device descriptor you'll need to read (using interface #0) which will then specify the interface numbers to use. The latter allows more flexibility to device manufacturers.
Sources:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/33140787
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7466?page=0,0 (note that some things have changed since that article was written, as noted in the above Stack Overflow thread)
the various USB specifications


Thank you for the detailed answer @telcoM! Out of curiosity is this info documented somewhere or is your answer from experience and/or knowledge of the source code? Interested to learn how to better dive in myself in the future.
